# Error using bracket argument of \cite within theorem titles

Tags: citing, overleaf, theorems

This error shows up only in Overleaf (plain online version), so either my local editor (TeXstudio) does not report it, or it is related to the editor. I have a fix to share if anyone encounters the same problem, but I would appreciate knowing the reason why it happens and how to properly avoid it.

**Problem** Using the optional argument of `\cite` in a `theorem` title breaks the citing feature, i.e. the citation key is displayed and the bibliography item is not generated. More precisely, using `\cite{thekey}` does not cause problems, but `\cite[the location]{thekey}` does.

**Current dirty fix** Put the whole title inside curly brackets.

**Minimal working example** The `bibi.bib` file:

```
@misc{alexander,
  title = {Alexandrov Geometry: Foundations},
  author = {Alexander, Stephanie and Kapovitch, Vitali and Petrunin, Anton},
  year = {2022},
}

@article{altarovici,
  title = {A General {{Hamilton-Jacobi}} Framework for Non-Linear State-Constrained Control Problems},
  author = {Altarovici, Albert and Bokanowski, Olivier and Zidani, Hasnaa},
  year = {2013},
}
```

The main.tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibi.bib}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition} 

\begin{document}

Outside of the title arguments, no problem to cite \cite{alexander}, 
and no problem either to precise the location as in \cite[Theorem 5]{alexander}. 
However, environments are not behaving the same.

\begin{mydef}[A first def \cite[Definition 16]{altarovici}]
    This definition title fails.
\end{mydef}

\begin{mydef}[{A second def \cite[Definition 7]{alexander}}]
    This definition title does not.
\end{mydef}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output using overleaf online:

[image: Pdf output of the aforementioned code]

Comment: That is not a dirty fix, that is **the** fix. The argument parser has no concept of matching brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument of `mydef` is `A first def \cite[Definition 16` so when that argument is used, the `\cite` argument is not closed.

Use

`\begin{mydef}[{A first def \cite[Definition 16]{altarovici}}]`

with extra brace group to hide the inner `[]`

This is unrelated to Overleaf and applies to all optional arguments defined by classic LaTeX2e constructs such as `\newcommand`. The versions defined by `ltcmd` (`xparse`) constructs such as `\NewDocumentCommand` do match nested `[]` constructs.